# Cannot open appx when download app from Windows Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, fiddler, windows-10-mobile, windows-store, appx

I'm using fiddler as proxy to get download URL of Windows Store apps.

Most of the time after catching URL, download appx/appxbundle and open it, windows show error `'Cannot open appx/appxbundle file'`.

When I want to open appx using WinRar, faced with error `'Unknown format or damaged'`. also i checked the error in Windows Powershell and see `error 0x80073cf0.`

I'm pretty sure, appx file downloaded completely but why cannot install app.

Comment: I use Charles to get the links and download the apps with Freedownloadmanager. Here the Appx(Bundle) files are fine and I can open them with 7Zip.

Comment: Excuse me @magicandre1981. I couldn't access my stackoverflow account right now, so i replay using other account. sometimes no problem in downloaded file, but just sometimes.

Comment: try to redownload the file. I always use freedownloadmanager. don't use IE

Comment: I test it using IDM(internet download manager) but after downloading 3 or 4 app, problem occurred.

Comment: if no problem, after copy url to idm, it's name change's to main app name, else downloaded file name doesn't change!!!

Comment: try fdm: http://freedownloadmanager.org/board/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=17330 for me it always worked

Comment: Thank you @magicandre1981, can you test this url: http://tlu.dl.delivery.mp.microsoft.com/filestreamingservice/files/4e5757f0-867a-4a24-a620-d8a9c5d7d6e0?P1=1489567158&P2=301&P3=2&P4=L2CDKsIuHF1SqZNqjOvkSL946DgqZSPlAE1xtveXJDI%3d

Comment: this link is only valid for a few minutes. post the link to the store, so that I can generate my own link

Answer (score -1):

APPX files downloaded from the store are encrypted so you can't just download an app and extract it's contents. This is just a part of the various mechanisms in place to protect the Intellectual Property of the those creating and releasing apps.

Comment: no, this is for SilverLight apps (XAP). they have a DRM header, appx files are not encrypted.

Comment: @magicandre1981 the question is tagged APPX and windows-10-mobile and specifically refers to appxbundle. Do you have a different question relating to xap files?

Comment: I know this, but not you. Your answer is valid for XAP files, not APPX. APPX are **NOT ENCRYPTED** in any ways. Have you now understood this?